# FOSUserBundle: Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

First of all, I know SO is full of questions like this but I tried to combine different config values according to those responses with no luck.

I'm using FOSUserBundle with my own *User* class and when submiting login form I get this error:

> Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical

Here are some bits of my code:

```
doctrine:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        # mappings:
        #     FOSUserBundle: ~
fos_user:
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Some variations tested include setting `auto_mapping: false` and/or uncommenting `mappings.FOSUserBundle: ~`

This is my user class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface
{
    const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $login;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", length=255)
     */
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * Método requerido por la interfaz UserInterface
     */
    public function equals(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->getLogin() == $user->getLogin();
    }

    /**
     * Método requerido por la interfaz UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Método requerido por la interfaz UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->getLogin();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set login
     *
     * @param string $login
     */
    public function setLogin($login)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
    }

    /**
     * Get login
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a role to the user.
     *
     * @param string $role
     */
    public function addRole($role)
    {
        $role = strtoupper($role);
        if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
            return;
        }

        if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
            $this->roles[] = $role;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the user roles
     *
     * Implements SecurityUserInterface
     *
     * @return array The roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
            $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
        }

        // we need to make sure to have at least one role
        $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * Set roles
     *
     * @param string $roles
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * Never use this to check if this user has access to anything!
     *
     * Use the SecurityContext, or an implementation of AccessDecisionManager
     * instead, e.g.
     *
     *         $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Boolean
     */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
    }

}
```

Login (`layout.html.twig` actually) template has been overriden and apparently renders properly, my versions are:

- Symonfy: Symfony version 2.8.2 - app/dev/debug
- "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3"

`console doctrine:schema:update`has been executed and it doesn't detect any more changes, although usernameCanonical or email do not exist in the DB table.

Thanks

Comment: The above code not contains any  `email` or `usernameCanonical` property/field.

Comment: They're supposed to be inherited from `BaseUser` class

Comment: BTW, `doctrine:schema:update` does not detect those fields as they don't exist in DB

Comment: With FOSUserBundle 1.3.x you have to extend `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` instead of `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` (see http://symfony.com/doc/1.3.x/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#a-doctrine-orm-user-class).

Comment: @xabbuh that was it!

Comment: @xabbuh - I  suggest you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FOSUserBundle 1.3.x you have to extend `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` instead of `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` (see http://symfony.com/doc/1.3.x/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#a-doctrine-orm-user-class).